# white-space:nowrap expands div?

Tags: html, css

I made code in css for `div .name` with width of 75% so that the text truncate if doesn't fit. But when I resize my window text stays same and my whole site is falls apart.

This is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="check_td"><input type="checkbox" name="products" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"</td>
    <td class="product_td">
        <div class="product">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img" src="<?php echo $row['img_path'].'/'.$row['img_name']; ?>">
            </div>
        <div class="name">
            <?php echo $row['product_name']; ?> // this is problem
        </div>                          
        <div class="list">
            <ul>
                <li>Prodavač: <a href="" style="color:black;"><strong><?php echo $data['username']; ?></strong></a>
                (<a href="">98% <img src="img/stars/star.png" width="18px" style="margin-bottom:-3px;"/></a>)
                </li>
                <li><?php echo $address['city']; ?></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="comm">
              <img src="icons/comment.png" width="23px"/>(6)
            </div>
        <div class="id"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="price_td">
                        <ul>
                            <li style="font-size:23px;">
                                <strong><?php echo $row['price']; ?> kn</strong>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <ul class="ship">
                                    <li>
                                        <?php echo $row['ship']; ?>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <strong><?php echo $row['ship_price']; ?> kn</strong>
                                    </li>                                           
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td class="button_td"><button class="menu_buttons1">Istaknite oglas &raquo;</button></td>
                </tr>
```

I also noticed that width I set don't work properly when I add `white-space:nowrap;`

```
.name{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:6px 0 10px 0;
  width:75%;
  font-size:20px;
  color:black;
  font-weight: 900;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

When I remove with in percents and set in pixels it works nice, but why I can't set my width of div class name in presents?

**EDIT:**
i added jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nwqoh931/

Comment: It would be helpful if you could produce a jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nwqoh931/

Comment: The problem is that width in tables doesn't work the way you want to. Tables work very hard to display everything in them, even if they have to bend the rules to do so. In this case, becoming wider than the body. Now there are no hardcoded widths in your fiddle, only percentages, so the div.name doesn't know what to make its width 75% of.

Answer (score 0):

**"**`white-space: nowrap;` **never expands a div."**

It just tells the `<div>` to disable wrapping the text inside it.

Explanation/Example:

```css
div{
 width: 100px; 
 background: yellow;
}

.whitespace-normal{
  white-space: normal;
}

.whitespace-nowrap{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitespace-normal">
  TESTING OF WHITESPACE
</div>
<i><b>Default White-Space:</b> The text inside the div is wrapped (creates new lines) based on div width.</i>
<br/><br/>
<div class="whitespace-nowrap">
  TESTING OF WHITESPACE
</div>
<i><b>No Wrap White-Space:</b> Disregard the width of div, Even it overflows. It prints the text exactly what it is. (no new lines)</i>
```

Comment: thank you for answer, so what can be my problem?, here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nwqoh931/

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: all table row elements shoul be visible, in my code is extended so i have to scroll horizontally

Comment: So you want to remove/prevent the horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: Remove the `white-space:nowrap;` in `.name` class. https://jsfiddle.net/nwqoh931/1/

Comment: and when i remove text is in 4 columns not in one